# Error 400 - Error returned by the application of the object - Tableau(Range).Group

Tags: vba, excel

I'm actually having difficulties with the code below.

It browses each Shapes of my worksheet and once he've checked the type of the shape he adds its ID in the array Tableau().

The line returning the error is the following :

```
Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Tableau).group <== it might be a detail but VBA Editor doesn't change group by Group.
```

This is the complete code below:

```
Sub Select()

    Dim Sh As Object
    Dim Tableau()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Loop on the ActiveSheet Shapes
    For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes

        If Sh.Type <> msoFormControl Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve Tableau(1 To i)
            Tableau(i) = Sh.ID
        End If
    Next Sh

    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    'Group shapes whom the ID is in the array
    Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Tableau).group '<== Error 400

    'Rename the group
    Sh.name = "Group" & CStr(Rnd)

    Sh.Copy

Exit Sub

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Tableau(i) = Sh.Name` instead?

Comment: do you have `Option Base 1` set? Otherwise, your counting on `I` and your `ReDim Preserve ...` look off.

Comment: I also just tested it with `Sh.Name` and it worked.

Comment: I've tryed with the name instead. And I've set up the array on Tableau(0 to i).

Comment: And I've set up the array on Tableau(0 to i). It is working but sometimes an error occur with Sh.Copy : "'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" But it is working anyway : My shape is Copied

Comment: OK I finally got it; Error 400 is when you did not selected the Sheet whom you are talking about in the code. I was asking : For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes so I had to select this sheet before. Thx all !!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SelectA()

Dim Sh As Object
Dim Tableau()
Dim i As Integer

'Loop on the ActiveSheet Shapes
For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Sh.Type <> msoFormControl Then

        ReDim Preserve Tableau(i)
        Tableau(i) = Sh.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next Sh

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

'Group shapes whom the ID is in the array
Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Tableau).Group

'Rename the group
Sh.Name = "Group" & CStr(Rnd)

Sh.Copy

Exit Sub
```

Errorcatch:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Thanks